# Checkboxes not returning information from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Trying to search through my database so that it can return my ingredients for each recipe. However when i am pressing the submit button nothing is coming up.

My database has :

```
recipeName: ....
    ing1: ... 
    ing2:... 
    ing3:... 
    etc etc
```

Now when the user clicks on certian checkboxes it should return that movie , however mine does not seem to work. Again i might be making a silly mistake but any help would be great .

PHP:

```
    $fields = array('recipe_ing1','recipe_ing2','recipe_ing3');
    $query = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE recipeName LIKE '%".$str."%'");
```

BTW i know 100% i should not be using these functions etc and be using PDO, this is a mini project which i am working on and for my use only i need to use these functions. I will be re doing anther version of this using the latest commands out there. 
Example of what i am trying to do : [Example](https://juicerecipes.com/ingredients/)

Anyway any help on this matter would be great.

Comment: Where are checkbox `values`?

Comment: @Fabio sorry just fixed that little problem :)

Comment: Is the first double quote after like in the right place?

Comment: are you sure that $_POST['serach'] is set? I don't see it. Also are you sure your query returns any rows?

Comment: In fact I think you have those quote marks around the ingredient mixed up

Comment: hmm i am not sure , i think i have got it right

Comment: @mr12086 hmm how should it look like?

Comment: Within the SQL string you open a single quote but close it with a double

Comment: @mr12086 sorry could you show me please, i am getting confused about this

Comment: Here `"$ign LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($ingredient).'%"';`

Comment: @Fabio thanks , but ye just changed it, but still nothing, i am not really sure what is the best way to make it work

Comment: An example of what i am trying to  do is here btw: https://juicerecipes.com/ingredients/

Comment: Where is search button?

Comment: @Fabio sorry missed it out, its there now

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="search" value="Submit">` use this and change the end of the query  to `LIKE '%".$str."%' "`

Comment: Sorry for the Like bit u mean change this : "$ign LIKE '%" to LIKE '%".$str."%'? cause that does not work at all , or i think i am doing something wrong

Comment: What it says , when i press the search button is could not search

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE recipeName LIKE '%".$str."%'"`

Comment: Also the button is missing the name, change as i told you

Comment: @Fabio ah sorry yes i did that, still when i press the search button , says could not search

Comment: @fabio means that you should add a `name` tag for your button. `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="search">`

Comment: @LoganWayne ah yes thanks logan , have just updated code on the site, but still when i press search , nothing comes up

Comment: `$output` variable is above your HTML file? They are in a same file, the PHP and HTML?

Comment: Its really weird, its bugging me , i means its just like a simple search through the Database, to look through the columns of the ingredients and if that column has the name Kale for example, it will return all the recipes with Kale

Comment: Any errors when submitting the form?

Comment: @LoganWayne none just Could not search which is the one i set up already

Comment: this is so frustrating i am sure i am missing something but got no clue what , the life of programming hey :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to execute your query:

```
SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE recipeName LIKE '%".$str."%'"
```

where `$str` is (*when `Kale` is selected for example*):

```
recipe_ing1 LIKE '%Kale%' OR recipe_ing2 LIKE '%Kale%' OR recipe_ing3 LIKE '%Kale%'
```

then your complete query would look like

```
SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE recipeName LIKE recipe_ing1 LIKE '%Kale%' OR recipe_ing2 LIKE '%Kale%' OR recipe_ing3 LIKE '%Kale%'
```

which is wrong.

You should change your query to:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE ".$str) or die("Could not search.");
```

You should also concatenate properly when assigning values to your `$str` variable:

```
$str[] = $ign." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($ingridient)."%'";
```

And would just like to remind you that `mysql_*` is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and at least use `mysqli_*`'s [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Ah thats great help i have changed that, however it says that this line : foreach ($_POST['ingredient'] as $ingredient){ has an error on it

Comment: Ah we have progress, its actually showing me every recipe , however obviously i want it so that it shows the recipes only with that certain ingredient in it

Comment: i added this btw to see if anything was going wrong : $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE ".$str) or die(mysql_error()); so used the mysql_error and says line 53 has Undefined variable however i am not sure if that plays a big part in this problem and also sorry on line 17 which is the one u posted above : $str[] = $ign." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($ingridient)."%'";

Comment: @Nevershow2016 - I think because `mysql_error()` is expecting an argument/parameter inside. Did you try selecting one ingredient first?

Comment: i actaully just got rid of the mysql_error and still get the errors popping up , and yes i did, dosent matter which one i choose will print all my recipes

Comment: I am so lost with this at the moment, no idea why its saying those lines are throwing those errors

Comment: What variable is undefined? What is the complete error message?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: ingridient in D:\Database\htdocs\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\ing.php on line 17

Comment: and the second one Notice: Undefined variable: rI4 in D:\Database\htdocs\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\ing.php on line 53

Comment: But like i said its showing all my recipes , so it is searching fine , it must be something else which is going on

Comment: Because there is no `$ingridient` variable. It is `$ingredient`. And you're not showing `$rl4` variable. What is inside it?

Comment: hmm i changed line 17 to ingredient but still showing the errors and r14 is going to be recipe_ing4 etc as in my database it goes up to recipe_ing6

Comment: Just found out the error , omg , thank you so so so so much man, you dont know how long i have been stuck on this, u are a great man for sticking by me, if i could give u 10k rep  i would

Comment: Hope u have a lovely day x